# Custom button is not update field for non admin user

Tags: custom-button, read-only

I've a object, custom button and two check box field on it.

The custom button which is updating the check box field to true.

from custom button java script code i'm calling apex class, after execution of apex class it should update the check box field on same object.

This is perfect working for system admin user,

but when i tried for non admin user it will not updating the checkbox to true but apex class is correct executing in this case

The check box field is read only from field accessibility for all profile.

why it is not updating for non admin user?

Code is.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/19.0/connection.js")} 
 {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/19.0/apex.js")} 

if("{!Patient_Services__c.Service_Invoiced__c}"== "0" || 
"{!Patient_Services__c.Service_Invoiced__c}"== "1" && "       {!$Profile.Name}"=="System Administrator") 
{
    if("{!Patient_Services__c.Ready_for_Billing__c}" == "0" && "{!Patient_Services__c.Who_to_Invoice__c}" == '' ) 
        { 
        alert('Please Select the Who To Invoice'); 
        } 
    else 
        if("{!Patient_Services__c.Ready_for_Billing__c}" == "0" && "{!Patient_Services__c.Who_to_Invoice__c}" != "null" ) 
        {

                if("{!Patient_Services__c.Added_to_Opty__c}"== "0" && ("{!Patient_Services__c.Who_to_Invoice__c}"=="Medicare Account" || "{!Patient_Services__c.Who_to_Invoice__c}"=="DVA Account")) 
                {

                    var r = confirm("Opportunity will now be created;\nDo you want to proceed?"); 
                    if(r == true) 
                    {
                        //alert("Opportunity now Created"); 
                        var a= sforce.apex.execute("CreateOpty","CreateOptywithps",{Id :"{!Patient_Services__c.Id}"}); 
                        // alert(a); 

                    if(a>0)
                        alert("Opportunity created Successfully for Medicare/DVA Account..!\nFor Opportunity Product Please see bottom of page");

                    else if(1)
                    alert("Opportunity not Created for Medicare/DVA Account.\nCheck Rate Card is Available or Billing Error log. Please Contact your System Administrator")

                    var b;
                    if("{!Patient_Services__c.Dispensing_Footwear_F049__c}"=="1")
                            {
                            b = sforce.apex.execute("CreateOptyforDispenfoot","CreateOptywithps",{Id :"{!Patient_Services__c.Id}"}); 

                        //  alert(b);
                            if(b>0)
                            alert("Opportunity created Successfully for Dispensing Footwear F049..!\nFor Opportunity Product Please see bottom of page");
                            else if(1)
                            alert("Opportunity not Created for Dispensing Footwear F049.\nCheck Rate Card is Available or Billing Error log.\nPlease Contact your System Administrator")
                            }

                    if(a>0 || b>0)
                            {
                            var c = new sforce.SObject("Patient_Services__c"); 
                            c.id = "{!Patient_Services__c.Id}"; 
                            c.Ready_for_Billing__c= "1"; 
                            result = sforce.connection.update([c]); 
                            window.location.reload(); 
                            }

                }
                }}
```

apex class is

```
global class CreateOpty{

 WebService static Integer CreateOptywithps(String Id)
{    .........
 }}
```

Comment: When you wrote your testmethods for this, did you include a runas section?  If so, can you inlcude the testMethod in the question, along with the relevant code you've currently written?

Comment: code to update  the check box field is in java script not in apex class, so No test class for it

Comment: can you share your code.

Comment: @Amol but you said that "from custom button java script code i'm calling apex class, after execution of apex class it should update the check box field on same object."  So you have an apex class.  What happens in your test method when you call this class using a runAs block?

Comment: @ Nick. i've written test class for apex class and called that apex class manually like' test.startTest();
        Integer p = CreateOpty.CreateOptywithps(ps.id);
        test.stopTest();'

Answer (score -1):

The edit access to the record is determined by the sharing access granted to the user unless you declare the apex class as without sharing..Please check field level security for those user

Comment: without sharing gives access to records, not FLS, FLS is not applied on apex context.

Comment: Please check my class declation also. and in field level security nothing access is given. In field accessibility it is make as Read only.

Comment: @sagar @ Haytham. i'm not getting this concept can you clarify me

Comment: FIrst thing is, my field update code which is written in javascript button code not in apex class, thus without sharing class is how beneficial here

Comment: @Amol in a class, you have code that selects a column that the user doesn't have access to, but you can't select a RECORD that the user doesn't have access to. you asked him to check field level security, where he should actually check Sharing Settings.